# Updating cell in excel using c# OLEDB connection

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I need your help with my problem:
I have a code here that updates cell in excel using c#. My problem is I have to open my excel file at first so that it can update the cell. What I need to do is update the cell without open the excel file before. Is it possible?

That's what I have so far:

```
    private void WOupdate()
    {
        string WOExcel07ConString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\t-jjtabije\\Desktop\\WO And CAO Update.xlsx;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text'";
        string conStr, sheetName;
        conStr = string.Empty;
        //Get the name of the First Sheet.
        using (OleDbConnection kuneksyon = new OleDbConnection(WOExcel07ConString))
        {
            using (OleDbCommand utos = new OleDbCommand())
            {
                using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter())
                {
                    utos.Connection = kuneksyon;
                    kuneksyon.Open();
                    DataTable dtExcelSchema = kuneksyon.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                    sheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                    kuneksyon.Close();
                    utos.Connection = kuneksyon;
                    utos.CommandText = "UPDATE [" + sheetName + "] SET [LTE WO]= '" + Path.GetFileName(WOfilename) + "', [REFARM LTE BW]='" + WObw.ToString() + "', [WO Status-LTE]='" + WOstat.ToString() + "' WHERE SITEID= '" +WOsiteid.ToString()+ "'";
                    kuneksyon.Open();
                    MessageBox.Show(WOfilename + WOsiteid + WOservice + WObw + WOstat);
                    oda.SelectCommand = utos;
                    utos.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    kuneksyon.Close(); ;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why you don't want to open the Excel file? You just don't want to start Excel? Or do you need to work on the file with a second process? I think it could be difficult to change sth. without locking the file for example. Please explain exactly why you need this, then we can better help you.

Comment: If the updated values are in the Excel file, then only your psychic abilities will determine what the updated values are.

Comment: I am making an automation app that will automatically update status in excel. so i dont want the user to open the excel to reduce the workload of the user.

Comment: So the user enters data then you need to update the Excel file with this newly entered data?

Comment: actually the user will DRAG & DROP the file in my app and will get the filename and update it on excel file without opening the excel file.

Comment: Save the data and update the Excel file later. I do not see how you could possibly change the values in the Excel file without opening it.

Comment: It gives me errors that the excel file is already open and locked from other user. this is why i dont want the user to open the excel file.

Comment: Hmmm and this small detail you felt was not pertinent to the original question?

Comment: It sounds like you will have to save the data in a list, table... then update it later. What does the Excel file contain?

Comment: my excel file acts as my database it contains filenumber, fileSite, filebandwidth. the filename has format  separated by # e.g (filenamenumber#filenamesiteID#filenamebandwidth) by the given file name my app will update the column in excel file.

Comment: Since Excel is not a database, you are either going to have to wait or save the data and update the excel file when it becomes available.